# Sending Email Through Lotus Notes From Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, email, lotus-notes, silverlight-5.0, comautomationfactory

We have a LOB application written in silverlight that currently shoots emails out through Outlook via:

```
Dim outlook = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
...
```

This works great when the user has elevated permissions in the application. My question is, does anyone know how we go about doing the same with Lotus Notes? We have a customer that is requesting it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Visual Basic to connect to Lotus Notes. See this IBM technote for an example: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21178583.

There are other ways such as using Java but in your case using Visual Basic sounds like the easiest way.

Comment: Is there any restrictions for this in regards to silverlight?

Comment: I don't know. If you can use Visual Basic from Silverlight, I don't think so.

Comment: It looks like you are using COM calls from within SilverLight for your Outlook solution.  The VB approach that @PerHenrikLausten is suggesting uses a COM interface (Lotus.NotesSession) to talk to the Lotus Notes/Domino system, but you can do this from any programming environment that supports COM.  So it seems to me that Silverlight must support COM if you are using it for Outlooks, therefore you can just make the COM calls for Lotus Notes directly from Silverlight and forget about VB.

Answer (score 0):

Can't LN use a SMTP interface? I don't know if IBM or third party has an adapter for Exchange, but they probably do.

Answer (score 0):

If you install IBM Notes on the Server, where the application is running, you could use [COM](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_designer.nsf/b3266a3c17f9bb7085256b870069c0a9/145e1cc3fdc801d485256c54004c938b?OpenDocument) to to similar stuff to what you do with Outlook.

The more "stable" or "professional" way would be to send the mail via SMTP to a SMTP server (IBM Domino, Exchange, postfix, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this site which use simple java program using the Notes jar,the jar will be available at where lotus note client is installed, in your system C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Lotus\Notes\jvm\lib\ext ,

[java-lotusdomino examples](http://www.vanbellenet.be/programming/java/lotusdomino/lotusdomino.html)

This could give you some ideas, how to send an email based on your needs.